# Android - Inheritance activities to make style

Tags: android, inheritance, layout, user-interface, android-activity

I am trying to do inheritance between activities in my application.
I want to create "general activity" style for my all application.

For example, this "general activity" includes `toolbar` and `statusbar`. I want to show both in each activity in my program.

I wrote the `BaseActivity` layout like that:

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar" />
<!-- Some control that can contain layout -->
<include layout="@layout/statusbar" />
```

And `MainActivity` that extends `BaseActivity`.
I want to insert in code the layout of the `MainActivity` to the specific space on `BaseActivity`.

Is it possible to do that? If yes, how can I set the layout of my inheritance activity in specific spase on this `BaseActivity`?
There is any control that can contain layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This can be possible from java side (Note that I didn't tried yet), here is an example [Reusing layout XML and the code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206643/reusing-layout-xml-and-the-code-behind).*

***This is can also be done via layouts.***

You have to make a separate layout (xml) for you toolbar or status bar, and then you have to include in required layout.

[Re-using Layouts](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) will be helpful link and [Android Layout Trick #2: Include to Reuse](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/)

Comment: I did the <include> tag in my BaseActivity. I just want to put layers in the middel of them. To do that I must to use the <include> tag in each activity? And the BaseActivity is not necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I did the <include> tag in my BaseActivity.'? Are you using include in java code?

Comment: No, in my xml layut file of my BaseActivity. I changed my question for more information...

Comment: Yes you have to include titlebar and statusbar in each layout in which you want to use. And this is not an inheritance behavior (as u are thinking), but you have one benefit, if you have any change in title or status you need to change only one/two file.

Comment: I understood, I just wanted to create a general style activity. I call that inheritance because in C#, for example, it can be done with inheritance. You can write general form and expand it in its sans form. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sure, its possible.
You'll do it like you do any Java inheritance.
You'll want to create a `BaseActivity` which will `extend` `Activity`.
Your other `Activities,` will `extend` `BaseActivity`.
Not always, but generally, you'll want your `BaseActivity` to be `abstract class`. You don't want to create instances of it.
So, you should call `setContentView` from the `EXTENDING` `Activity`. That way each `Activity` will have its own layout.

Comment: I have `BaseActivity` and `MainActivity`. How can I put the layout of my `MainActivity` in the specific space on the `BaseActivity`?

Comment: I see, but if I call to `setContentView` its deletes my toolbar and statusbar, and show the new layout insted. How can I put the new layout between them? There is an control that can contain a layout?

Comment: Hmmm.. in that case I think you'll want to use the <include> Tag in your XML. Make your statusbar and toolbar in a different XML and <include> then where ever you want.  Example:
<include
        android:id="@+id/status_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/YOUR_LAYOUT_HERE />

Comment: I did it in my `BaseActivity` layout. Thats the reson that I have created this class. You say that I must to use the `<include>` tag in each activity? And the `BaseActivity` is not necessary?