# Equal unique ID's in different Activities

Tags: android

I'm wondering, what happens if I declare two unique ID's in 2 different activities? The ID's have the same name and are declared as unique (@+id) .. Is there any collision of ID's ? When I call the Id in the code of the second activity, is going to have any problem, what ID is it going to call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reusing layout XML and the code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206643/reusing-layout-xml-and-the-code-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same Id does not matter to your code
Say if you are in Activity `A` then you set layout for it using

```
setContentView()
```

so it search this id to this layout only

### Declaring Same ID's in one layout

#### 1. Even every activity may have the same name of ids there is no Problem

#### Its a good practice to reuse of ID names and also easy to handle with same ids in different Layout

### Declaring Same ID's in one layout

If you do this there is also no problem untill unless you don't access it from Activity class or from java file coz at that time compiler will be puzzled between all the similar of and **it will pick the first occurrence** of that name ID.

and also if you don't want to access it from backend its still not an issue

Comment: Right, thanks.. But if I declare same ID's in the same activity, only one can be unique right?

Comment: It is unpractical to declare ID two or more times in one layout coz if you wanted to access that view then compiler will be puzzled between two but if you don't want to use then it will show only warning nothing else

Comment: I'm really sorry but I need 15 points of reputation to do that

Answer (score 1):

You won't have any problems.

Examples:

- The `android.R.id.home` is the id of the ActionBar icon in **every** `Activity`.
- `android.R.id.list` is used by every `ListActivity`.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I need 15 points of reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The generated ID will be the same. However, there will be no problem because the two views exist in two different layout XML. As long as the ID does not appear more than once in each XML, no problem will occur.